# Applying environment variables in Google Cloud Console UI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables

How can I apply environment variables in Google Cloud Console UI? I'm trying to deploy Node.js backend server and React frontend app in Google Kubernetes Engine.
I changed environment variables in the config yaml file and saved. But It is not applied automatically on the Deploy. How can I apply it?

Comment: Can you show what your YAML looks like?

Comment: Sorry, It has a lot of sensitive info such as IDs. So I can not share all. But I didn't change anything special. I used the only browser-based UI instead of Terminal. So, Kubernetes Engine made the YAML file automatically. 
I opened up the configuration panel in the Kubernetes Engine in the Google Cloud Platform. And I edited values as a test.
from
ORIGIN: http://localhost 
to 
ORIGIN: http://123 
nothing special. and I saved. But the value is not changing from http://localhost . I am wondering if there is apply button or something like that.

Comment: You would not see fields like that in a Deployment object. Were you editing a ConfigMap or Secret perhaps? Changes to those do not trigger a deployment update, you need to run `kubectl rollout restart deployment -n $namespace $deploymentname`.

Comment: I was editing ConfigMap. Yeah. I noticed I have to run kubectl command from terminal.
Thanx for your help! It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments, Pods must be restarted to pick up env var changes from external data sources.